# Upgrade Angular 4 to 5: NgFor and Component create twice

Tags: angular

after upgrading angular from 4 to 5, if have that problem that ngFor will run always twice, although the list where the ngFor is linked, has only one element. Additional some components will destroy before ngOnInit is called. I tried to reproduce this behavior on plunker, without any results. I have no idea how to fix this issue :|
Any ideas? On Angular 4.4.6 everything runs without any problems.

```
"@angular/cli": "^1.7.3",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.9",
"@angular/language-service": "5.2.9",
"@angular/animations": "^5.2.9",
"@angular/common": "^5.2.9",
"@angular/compiler": "^5.2.9",
"@angular/core": "^5.2.9",
"@angular/forms": "^5.2.9",
"@angular/http": "^5.2.9",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.9",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.9",
"@angular/platform-server": "^5.2.9",
"@angular/router": "^5.2.9",
```

I used https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com/ to upgrade from 4 to 5, to get the edge cases during upgrade.

Big thxs for support.

Comment: share the code?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what's going on without seeing the code. If you suspect that it's an upgrade issue and your Angular 4 project was generated by Angular CLI, run the `ng update` command in the root dir of your project, and it'll properly update all your dependencies in package.json.